# failbit is set when reading quoted string at the end of a std::string using std::basic_istringstream and std::quoted

Tags: c++, istringstream

I try to tokenize a string such that

- `"word1 word2 word3 word4"` will be tokenized to 4 strings: `"word1"`, `"word2"`,  `"word3"` and `"word4"`
- `"word1 \"word2 word3\" word4"` will be tokenized to 3 strings: `"word1"`, `"word2 word3"` and `"word4"`

I have written a function `tokenizeQuoted()` which does the job. That function does check after reading each token if an error occurred by checking the `failbit` of the stream.

```cpp
#include <cstring>
#include <cwchar>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

// Tokenize a string using std::quoted
template <typename CharType>
std::vector<std::basic_string<CharType>> tokenizeQuoted(const std::basic_string<CharType> &input)
{
    std::basic_istringstream<CharType> iss(input);
    std::vector<std::basic_string<CharType>> tokens;

    std::basic_string<CharType> token;
    while (!iss.eof())
    {
        iss >> std::quoted(token);
        if (iss.fail())
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("failed to tokenize string: '" + input + "'; bad bit = " + (iss.bad() ? "true" : "false"));
        }
        tokens.push_back(token);
    }

    return tokens;
}

int main() {
    const std::string inputMars = "\"hello mars\"!"; // note the '!' at the end
    const std::string inputEarth = "\"hello earth\"";
    const auto mars = tokenizeQuoted(inputMars); // OK
    const auto earth = tokenizeQuoted(inputEarth); // failbit is set
    return mars.size() + earth.size();
}
```

In general the function [works](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAewK4BcAOGA0BLECAY2QFtM8AbAUwCcA5AQ1OpAHIAPADgDYBaHgBYA1MCJFhARgDMAOgBMbHNQAmedMlp4VISTgBmyAHboAykUY1dgg8fQBVAM7UACh3YAGJQCtdOAO60jJjskmwAlDiU7ACsSkaeSsjsAPIY2OjCyPrC3PxCouJScvLCEADCZBQ0tMIApPLSkuFK6InhkQjUjCp0hJHRbIJKpCAxHjgJbF44yWxKjiATbdMROHCwMIggJL0AomoatPiE%2BlTURsysbGG2JuaWrJI2hiZOru6rOL56lIxGoCIDQAQiCcM4aER0HhjIQLipKpRUKQEvJlEYVAAZPBGaj0ZEAIz60h4OEwyEc6hhRkRyNRZIpVOM2Nx%2BNIRNoIBJ4OokOhxlM6EYtHQtJRfgh1Ch1MFwvQLLxhL6ekcQpFYoSKrV8pxivZysijjQtCI1wa0hxRCRvXq0nKRFVWgBdWkezqHgAgubLdbqLb7f4iAhhS63Z7vUYragbS7yjDSP88JhQ%2B6vY0fdG/bHHI7uqQU%2BH05Hff7Vb0OKbMOgC2mLcXM6X0E7gDWI1GY3aAG5So6tz0Aen7wgAKsgANYXPAALz9jGEjpxwGEqEpAPn6B0IAAjqhkOhVKn9%2BQ/vv/egAJ6YC5XYTlYO0YeX6g1ssgEDdqGabMbt8ExiUogAH0F2dO072FR8rxTV1hA0CcjGnagAEVd33FRiGMVV103P8AOAptF1jcCHyfUN6nkHgcQycJUzqAB2UFPWEZjsN/f88CAvAQOAXNmCI%2B9IOfGCuMcCAqIwGjpEYj0WNY98ey/O1XxAXCOPw5t%2BIg0jXTIuCLkcF1pNTWTlNUoDuM0kioJgvSjEM4yWP8BBzjKMAwBE2RqGyCAOgc5j6Ok2TZJE203Rg5Sdz3VQIFsyTAqC5i8ByMSc1kfRGCoHyaKYhL6gYvzcuY9AEFoZB/Dk2hUBMPAWEAuhStoCAGnkdLzhUWDkA6%2BDEPXZsQGEMA2Ga8jgWEcTMhBcj5EGwzhD/dqCXUW0ABEppGsoPPmnzbQAMSmptUGfeRSn65r0soZxmt8qSCtk%2BjltuljbMcWRsEcBBAL/Igxxi8cLjigr7tonLmNoah0FQWgjC6/T7PDOiHvDT0cUyBMcW2gKCpIIwsOU7ixqMDIAFlhUcFaprqGJymarpKEoTqE1oAyqeatzmtmwdhCMKLYK6Aa2DcwbhEYTJir9eEscwzI8YItdxr2OUEHJ9mWeO2n6eEboRQQSnqeO9mbpB4RsawxgMAZ0nydsxCUKi9DxpJpmAaNk3MjNjRNcVq2/oQmdbbQsTCYwBXtedmSWLBiGoeERmXspGcMfkUateK2R4%2BoHy4a9BG1kGOJJkSWZ2D10Ek/nY1TXIppWnaTpul6TkfJwMcxgmQZhgLr45gWJYcBWLxIg2bYSHIc5jgIDDR5qEBgBkNEzkofcmcIAlC8Wy5aHPUIlHX4VzxSAlvB7becBHlgTBSIxKC3r5egJVBgHKSwLpP3oEwBKxb7wMHpW7RYvmoBwKUGBrgzBRryQulA8AEiCJvSovRC4EVGDcNY%2Bg/g8QAGp4GoP4FIV4pi3FeGYCwVhnh3AcM4NwhcfhRH%2BICEEYIoEEkWJASIyAqzUn/nwMsLplpAiTiCSQdEkjdloFoXoLCm6SmlLCCA8INR%2BHhAqNkHI/DkkpPyGkyAkTij0OopkRhlFKk5CqXkPYZTagUaYvkFi5RGP1CY8EljtF0glNqexqjmjggrk8AYsR4iFzmLkXgAgRBiAkDIBQZQDjqE0FXZoNdVgdGbq3KI7AO6jHGJ3GY3dwS937hEPxbBFA4EyRMKYOT2CJIHpEFukgPBt3YNIAJXcql91rjgURlJYSCCAA%3D%3D). But in case the input string ends with a quoted string (like `"say \"good day\""`), the failbit is set. I would not expect that. What can I do to reliably detect errors and still be able to extract quoted strings at the end of the sequence?

Comment: FYI: [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't give a definite answer as to why it is happening, but I did find a workaround. Basically, I observed that even though `std::quoted` is moving the position indicator to the correct place, it may not be doing an eof check and setting the bit correctly. The workaround is to check if the eof bit is set, and if it is not calling `peek()`. Peeking the next value will do nothing if we are not at the end of the file, but if we are it will correctly update the bits. I prove that this works by printing the token extracted, as well as the stream bits before and after calling peek.

```
#include <cstring>
#include <cwchar>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

// Tokenize a string using std::quoted
template <typename CharType>
std::vector<std::basic_string<CharType>> tokenizeQuoted(const std::basic_string<CharType> &input)
{
    std::basic_istringstream<CharType> iss(input);
    std::vector<std::basic_string<CharType>> tokens;
    std::basic_string<CharType> token;

    while (iss >> std::ws && !iss.eof())
    {
        token.clear();
        iss >> std::quoted(token);
        if (iss.fail())
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("failed to tokenize string: '" + input + "'; bad bit = " + (iss.bad() ? "true" : "false"));
        }
        tokens.push_back(token);
        std::cerr << "Token : " << token << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "Before: " << iss.good() << iss.eof() << iss.fail() << iss.bad() << std::endl;
        if (!iss.eof()) {
            iss.peek();
        }
        std::cerr << "After : " << iss.good() << iss.eof() << iss.fail() << iss.bad() << std::endl << std::endl;
    }

    return tokens;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> inputs {
        R"("hello mars"!)",
        R"("hello earth")",
        R"(no quotes)",
        R"("unfinished quotes)",
        R"(")",
        R"("")",
        R"(""")",
        R"("""")",
        R"( "leading whitespace")",
        R"("trailing whitespace" )",
    };

    for (const auto& input : inputs)
    {
        std::cout << "Tokenizing '" << input << "'\n";
        try {
            auto tokens = tokenizeQuoted(input);
            for (const auto & token : tokens)
            {
                std::cout << " - '" << token << "'\n";
            }
        } catch (std::runtime_error& e) {
            std::cout << e.what() << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Note how the eof bit updates to the correct state after calling `peek()` in the "hello earth" extraction.

Comment: Your solution is not bad. It gives expected results in most cases I tested except for when a quoted string is followed by trailing whitespace: [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/oWTqvTzq8).

Comment: This is because calling `std::quoted` on only whitespace will always throw an error. If you want to avoid this from happening you should read in all whitespace before calling `std::quoted`.  Here is your demo with this change added, and I have updated my code to reflect this as well.

https://godbolt.org/z/Y1hn8949a

Answer (score 1):

The rules are [documented](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/quoted):

> 4. b) Otherwise (if the first character is the delimiter):
>
>    1. Turns off the `skipws` flag on the input stream.
>    2. Empties the destination string by calling `s.clear()`.
>    3. Extracts characters from `in` and appends them to `s`, except that whenever an escape character is extracted, it is ignored and the next character is appended to `s`. Extraction stops when `!in == true` or when an unescaped `delim` character is found.
>    4. Discards the final (unescaped) `delim` character.
>    5. Restores the `skipws` flag on the input stream to its original value.

What this means is that you cannot reliably determine whether the quoted string was properly formed by purely using the I/O manipulator. It is too simple.

That being said, if you add a bit of extra debugging information where you are throwing the exception, you'll see that the failure actually happens *after* you processed the token and actually happens when you try (and fail) to extract the next one:

```
while (!iss.eof())
{
    token.clear();
    iss >> std::quoted(token);
    if (iss.fail())
    {
        throw std::runtime_error(
            "failed to tokenize string: '" + input + "'"
            "; token: '" + token + "'"
            "; extracted: " + std::to_string(tokens.size()) + ""
            "; bad bit = " + (iss.bad() ? "true" : "false"));
    }
    tokens.push_back(token);
}
```

This throws:

```
failed to tokenize string: '"hello earth"'; token: ''; extracted: 1; bad bit = false
```

You can see that you already processed one token, and then failed to process the next one. That's because the EOF bit was not set on the stream. This is expected because the closing double-quote ended extraction.

It quickly gets messy and unintuitive when relying the various stream error bits for parsing. You probably want to handle specific error scenarios such as unterminated quoted strings, while still handling empty strings.

A more intuitive approach might be to tokenize the string using a regular expression. You can even use a `std::regex_iterator` and then parse each detected string with `std::quoted`, since by that stage you'll know it's properly formed.

Comment: Did I understand correctly that extracting double-quoted string *does not set the EOF bit* if at the end of the stream, but extracting non-quoted *does set the bit* it at the end of the stream?

Comment: Yes. The rules state that when handling a quoted string, the extraction stops when an unescaped delimiter is encountered. This means that no further characters will be extracted and so the stream will not hit EOF as part of that operation. When handling an unquoted string, you _will_ hit EOF if trying to extract more non-whitespace characters and there are none.